# GUI builder for JSF or Primefaces

Tags: jsf-2

Is there any UI-designer aid (Like Scene Builder is a useful screen designing aid for JavaFX application / Flash Builder plugin of eclipse is a useful screen designing aid for Flex application) to make screen design easy in JSF / Primefaces.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I remember you have few options to do this (mostly depending on which IDE you prefer). First is [Oracle JDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/downloads/index.html) which is only one with built-in support for this, second is [NetBeans Visual Web plugin](http://netbeans.org/community/magazine/html/03/visualwebdev/) and finally there is also [Web Page Editor](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jst.jsf.doc.user/html/gettingstarted/wpe/wpe_getting_started.html) for Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Recommending VWP in NB is kinda moot seeing as the plugin has been retired after NB 6.7.1. Even then, it was tied to Woodstock JSF components, one of the worst I've had the displeasure of working with. The eclipse plugin looks nice tho.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse. Thanks a lot. As of now the Web Page Editor is helpful

Comment: @kolossus I was just listing all the possibilities, I thought that this one is worth mentioning

Answer (score 0):

```
For using **ADF** - JDeveloper covers almost everything
For using **woodstocks,ICEFaces** - Netbeans have the plugins for visual page design
For using **PrimeFaces**, Netbeans is having CRUD code generators, but not the drag and drop UI component plugins.
```

Ideally, as the UI code is much of a XML format it should not be a big issue do design drag and drop plugins. Still I don't know why we are not having powerful plugins for the primefaces.